# SqliteDataReader and duplicate column names when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sqlite

Is there a documentation/specification about Sqlite3 that would describe would is supposed to happen in the following case?

Take this query:

```
var cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT Items.*, Files.* FROM Items LEFT JOIN Files ON Files.strColName = Items.strColName");
```

Both `Items` and `Files` have a column name "*strColName*". If an entry exists in `Files`, it will be joined to the result, if not, it will be NULL.
Let's assume I always need the value of *strColName*, no matter if it is coming from `Items` or from `Files`. If I execute a reader:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If there is a match in `Files`, `reader["strColName"]` will obviously contain the correct result because the value is set and it is the same in both tables. But if there wasn't a match in `Files`, will the NULL value of `Files` overwrite the non-NULL value of `Items`?

I'm really looking for some specification that defines how a Sqlite3 implementation has to deal with this case, so that I can trust either result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no problem returning multiple columns labelled with the same name.
However, the columns will always be returned in exactly the same order they are written in the `SELECT` statement.
So, when you are searching for `"strColName"`, you will find the first one, from `Items`.

It is recommended to use explicit column names instead of `*` so that the order is clear, and you can access values by their column index, if needed (and you detect incompatible changes in the table structure).

Comment: Expressed differently, you say that the 2nd column with the same name will not overwrite the value of the first. However, if the first was NULL and the second would not, the value would be NULL.

Comment: Yes; you get two (independent) columns, and `reader["strColName"]` will find the first one.